# Digital numbers recognition with Opencv + OCR on android

Tags: android, opencv, ocr

i'm currently developing an android application to recognize digital numbers of an electricity meter. i've done most of the work but i still not getting a good result. 80% of the time i get a false one.

This is an example (i'm testing with a kitchen scale which is very similar to the meter) :

**Original photo :**
[image]

**image after cropping and processing with OpenCV :**
[image]

**image after OCR (expected result that was obtained after several shots) :**
[image]

**image after OCR (unexpected result which is obtained often) :**
[image]

**Method used to process the image with OpenCV :**

```
public Bitmap Bildverarbeitung (Bitmap image){

    Mat tmp = new Mat (image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(image, tmp);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(tmp, tmp, new Size(3, 3), 0);
    Imgproc.threshold(tmp, tmp, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
    Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, image);
    return image;
}
```

I used two trained data but only one works better :

[traineddata that works good](https://github.com/adri1992/Tesseract_sevenSegmentsLetsGoDigital)

[traineddata that doesn't work](https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr)

can anyone help me get better results.. Is there any changes that i can do? or other methods that i can apply ? thanks in advance

Comment: I guess it could be due to the gaps in the digits, If you reduce the gaps in the various segments of the digit then the accuracy may go a bit high. The second link you attached seems to be trained upon images without gaps.

Comment: Do you know how to fill the gaps using opencv on android ?

Comment: You would have to try various methods such as: erosion, dilation, downscale then upscale, blurring etc and see which one works best

Comment: Thanks @zdar i'll try to apply them. I have an other question : is it possible that OCR is not the best option here? Is there an other approach? Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello user3816569 I am studying computer vision and I want to make a similiar application for another field. Did you resolve your issue? since you have black text over white background you can use the open morphological operator (which is a erode then dilate) and test until you close the gaps as @ZdaR said. Instead of OCR I would use HOG (look for HOG in google and handwritting recognition) hope it helps. Check: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez I didn't go back to that project to be honest but I've been working on machine learning for about 3 months now and i suggest that you give it a try especially it's getting easier to implement it since the AI field is improving everyday... take a look at tensorflow and it's object detection API I think doing a similar project to this with machine learning you will get much much better results than with openCV or other traditional methods..

Comment: @user-007 excellent thanks a lot one more reason to learn machine learning